# Is there a way to add shipping to paymentIntent with stripe and node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am able to create a paymentintent in the backend like this:

```
 const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: "USD",
  customer: id,
  automatic_payment_methods: {enabled:true}
});
```

And it works perfectly, but when I try to add the shipping address given by the client like this:

```
 const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: "USD",
  customer: id,
  shipping: {
    address: req.body.address,
  },
  automatic_payment_methods: {enabled:true}
});
```

It never sends the response, and I don't get any errors at all so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I checked stripe API and it shows in the documentation that you can provide a shipping address. I don't want to attach it to the customer I created because they may have a different shipping address each time. I would rather attach it to the payment intent.

FYI here is the req.body.address that is being sent:

```
address: {
        "city": "Nashville",
        "country": "US",
        "line1": "3230 Random Address",
        "postal_code": "38118",
        "state": "TN",
      }
```

And I can confirm that it doesn't matter what the line1 is, because when I attached it to the createCustomer, it showed the address perfectly fine through stripe's end.

The entire post code:

```js
paymentRouter.post('/create-payment', isAuth, expressAsyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
  try {
    // check if customer exist in stripe
    var customer_exist = await stripe.customers.list({
      email: req.body.email,
      limit:1,
    })

    if(customer_exist){
      var id = customer_exist.data[0].id
    } else {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.body.email,
        name: req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName,
      });
      var id = customer.id
    }

    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: req.body.amount,
      currency: "USD",
      customer: id,
      shipping: {
        address: req.body.address,
      },
      automatic_payment_methods: {enabled:true}
    });

    res.send({
      clientSecret: payment.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({
      error: {message: error.message,}
    });
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course I found the solution as I post my problem.

It seems I was missing the shipping name. So I added the shipping name and it works perfectly now. And of course the error did not print because I did not console.log it until now.

[Edit]: so the documentation does show name is a requirement and I completely missed it somehow. Issue resolved now and here is what I implemented:

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: "USD",
  customer: id,
  shipping: {
    name: req.body.firstName + " " + req.body.lastName,
    address: req.body.address,
  },
  automatic_payment_methods: {enabled:true}
});
```